# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading ag-grid-ng2

Tags: angular, systemjs, ag-grid

after copy pasting a the the code of one component of the project in https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example, I have the following error:

"Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ag-grid-ng2/main(…)"

I have in my component.ts file, the following:

```
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import {AgComponentFactory} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/missions/dashboard/index.html',
    selector: 'brandbassador-app',
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
    providers: [AgComponentFactory]
})

...

constructor(..., private _viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef,
            private agComponentFactory:AgComponentFactory) { }
```

And in my HTML, I have:

```
 <ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-     fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
```

In my package.json, I have the following dependencies:

```
"ag-grid": "~5.2.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "~5.2.0",
"ag-grid-ng2": "~5.2.0",
```

My angular2 version is 2.0.0-rc.5 and my systemjs version is 0.19.36. I tried to use the systemjs version of the project example in the github. The project is compiled without any errors or warnings related to this problem.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Did you include the ag-grid-ng2 in the SystemJS file (or better yet, can you post your config for SystemJS)?

Comment: u solved this? if so plz provide how u did it.